# Jquery new div fadIn effect by reloading a div

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, reload

I have a div "content", in this div I have several div "comment", I'm reloading the div "content" every 5 second, and I would like to fadeIn every new comments. For this, every comment has an id which is an integer, so basically what I'm doing is : 
I'm saving the id of the last comment in a variable "lastComment", and when I'm reloading the div "content", I'm using if($(".comment").attr(id) > lastComment) { alert('ok') }

But it doesn't work, first it reloads the div and instead of saying 'ok' straight I need to wait 5 more seconds, here my code :

```
var lastComment = $('.comment:last').attr('id');
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#content').load('fullscreen.php?image='+$('.imageBig').attr('id')+' #content');
    if($('.comment').attr('id') > lastComment){
        alert('ok');
    }
}, 5000);
```

please any idea?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `.load()` for your use case, since that is already designed to automatically change/remove content in an HTML element on AJAX completion. You should consider going low level and invoking `$.ajax()` instead for the custom logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is your `jQuery selector` problem, in the if condition you should specify last `div.comment` because `var lastComment = $('.comment:last').attr('id');` statement will assign last element once after this `setInterval` works and new last div comment will changed so alert not works.

```
var lastComment = $('.comment:last').attr('id');
setInterval(function()
{
    $('#content').load('fullscreen.php?image='+$('.imageBig').attr('id'),function(){
        if($('.comment:last').attr('id') > lastComment){
            alert('ok');
        }
    });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: If you put the `if` statement inside the load callback then it will do what he wants, without having to wait 5 seconds after a load ;)